# How to Ensure Execution of Finally Block in Airflow DAG Despite Exception in Python Code?

Tags: python, sql-server, airflow

I have the following code, and under normal circumstances, it won't fail in Airflow. To make the DAG fail in case of a certain situation, I added a ValueError. However, in the event of a failure, the finally block, which is crucial, doesn't get executed. How can I avoid this situation?

```py
try:
    dump_tables(mssql_engine=mssql_engine, tables_list=tables_for_db_connection)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error during database operation: {str(e)}")
    raise ValueError
finally:
    mssql_engine.dispose()
```

Comment: How do you know the `finally` block isn't being hit?

Comment: @Xedni I've put a print statement there. It won't hit.